# PHP: cut out ALL sequences within a string until dot

Tags: php, string, preg-replace

I have a string in PHP 5.6 that contains sequence(s) I need to extract into a new string. But we struggle with the code as I am new to php.

**Example: ($searchstring)**
"We got an example here which covers it to 99% all and this sentence is already part of it. Because this is the first Markerword: with a lot of other things like commata, special characters ä, ü, ß or % and more in it. This proper Markerword: contains more of it multiple times and in caotic characters. If the Markerword: contains this, then cut the whole sequence out - until the first dot after that markerword. And if there are other sentences or even just words inbetween or at the end or before we ignore them all."

The seqeunce is somewhere inbetween and there could be only 1 time such a sequence or multiple times like 2 times or 3 times or 5 times...

The sequence itself comes always with a variable length and with diffrent words/numbers. But it begins and ends with the same pattern which is:
Start: "**Markerword:**"
End: "**.**" (first dot after "Markerword:")
Inbetween the sequences we need to extract there are no full stops.

I got a code but it only extracts one sequence (the last one) from the string. But if there are more they are skipped/not taken.

Code I have which does not work properly 100%:

```
    $resultstring = false;
if (strpos($searchstring, "Markerword:") !== false){
        preg_match('/(Markerword:([^.]+))/', $searchstring, $matches);
            $resultstring= $matches[0];
            $stopPos = strpos($resultstring, "  ");
            if ($stopPos !== false) {
            $resultstring= substr($resultstring,0,$stopPos + 1);
                }
            }
```

How can I take out all of them that they are like this?

**Desired outcome from the example above:**
Markerword: with a lot of other things like commata, special characters ä, ü, ß or % and more in it. Markerword: contains more of it multiple times and in caotic characters. Markerword: contains this, then cut the whole sequence out - until the first dot after that markerword."

Comment: no, but work ://
it is to extract product ingredients of product sets and split them afterwards...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$searchstring = "We got an example here which covers it to 99% all and this sentence is already part of it. Because this is the first Markerword: with a lot of other things like commata, special characters ä, ü, ß or % and more in it. This proper Markerword: contains more of it multiple times and in caotic characters. If the Markerword: contains this, then cut the whole sequence out - until the first dot after that markerword. And if there are other sentences or even just words inbetween or at the end or before we ignore them all.";

preg_match_all('/\bMarkerword:[^.]+\./', $searchstring, $m);
$result = implode(' ', $m[0]);
echo $result;
```

**Output:**

```
Markerword: with a lot of other things like commata, special characters ä, ü, ß or % and more in it. Markerword: contains more of it multiple times and in caotic characters. Markerword: contains this, then cut the whole sequence out - until the first dot after that markerword.
```

[Regex explanation](https://regex101.com/r/78EZOl/1)

Comment: thank you a lot! Combined with strip_tags I can remove HTML code and it works great!